# FPDI FPDF add page to PDF

Tags: php, fpdf, fpdi

I have a PDF file, and I want to add a new second page with about 3 lines of text generated by PHP. I figure FPDI to import the PDF file and FPDF to add the 3 lines of text to a second page. Can't find a tutorial anywhere, not sure how to go about this.

This is FPDI ==> https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/

- I want to generate a second page with PHP to add to the already created and uploaded PDF. This is why I put FPDF.

Still being put on hold because of being "too broad" Jeff. What does it take to fully describe what I'm saying here?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Jacob! Unfortunately your question is too broad for this site. We'll be happy to help you with the specific problems you encounter while programming your stuff, but you have to try and post your code before. Please see “[How do ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)” for more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see manual [here](https://manuals.setasign.com/fpdi-manual/). 
The following sample code shows how to use FPDI.

```
  $pdf = new FPDI();

 $pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile("Fantastic-Speaker.pdf");
 $tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1, '/MediaBox');

 $pdf->addPage();
 $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 10, 10, 90);

 $pdf->Output();
```

Comment: That just puts text on top of my PDF. How do I put it on a second page.

Comment: ok I figured it out.

If you want to add more pages you just keep putting $pdf->addPage();

So if you wanted to do 2 pages it would look like this:

`$pdf = new FPDI();

 $pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile("Fantastic-Speaker.pdf");
 $tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1, '/MediaBox');

 $pdf->addPage(); <-- our first page
 $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 10, 10, 90);

$pdf->addPage(); // <-- our second page

$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica');
$pdf->SetTextColor(200, 0, 0);

// now write some text above the imported page
$pdf->SetXY(40, 83);
$pdf->Write(2, 'THIS IS JUST A TEST');

 $pdf->Output();`